# Unable to see the textboxes that are loaded dynamically

Tags: asp.net

Please find my aspx and codebind files, I dont understand why am I unable to see the textboxes on my page once the code is deployed.
ascx code

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" >

<asp:ListItem Text="one" Enabled="true" Value="1" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem> 
<asp:ListItem Text="two" Enabled="true" Value="2" ></asp:ListItem>

</asp:DropDownList>
```

I would like to get the textbox dynamically loaded at the change of dropdown box and get the values entered in the textboxes into the result textbox.Once i change the dropdown box, i get the texboxes, but when I click the button , the textboxes disappear...I need to use the view state but where and how do I use it to get this code working pls help me

Please find my codeattached.

```
 public partial class DropdowndynamicUserControl : UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void createtextboxes(int i)
    {
        DynPanel.Visible = true;
        for (int counter = 0; counter <= i; counter++)
        {
            TextBox tb = new TextBox();
            tb.Width = 150;
            tb.Height = 18;
            tb.TextMode = TextBoxMode.SingleLine;
            tb.ID = "TextBoxID" + (counter + 1).ToString();
            tb.Text = "EnterTitle" + counter;
            tb.Visible = true;
            tb.EnableViewState = true;
            DynPanel.Controls.Add(tb);
            DynPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));

        }


    }

    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i;

        string selection = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();

        if (selection == "1")
        {
            i = 1;
            createtextboxes(i);
        }
        else if (selection == "2")
        {
            i = 2;
            createtextboxes(i);
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        readtextboxes();

    }

    public void readtextboxes()
    {
        string x = string.Empty;
        for (int a = 0; a < DynPanel.Controls.Count; a++)
        {
            foreach (Control ctrl in DynPanel.Controls)
            {
                if (ctrl is TextBox)
                {
                    x = ((TextBox)ctrl).Text;
                }
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding all of your TextBox controls to a panel whose property is set to `Visible="false"`. If a panel is not visible, none of its controls will be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `base.CreateChildControls();`

inside

`protected override void CreateChildControls()`